# VBA copy data from one sheet to another (to the blank cells)

Tags: vba, excel, loops

I would like to copy data from sheet `INV_LEDGERS`into `Ready to upload`sheet, but the sheet `Ready to upload` already contains some data and therefore I want to loop through the column A in `Ready to upload` sheet until it will find the blank cell and then paste the data from `INV_LEDGERS`.

```
    Sub CopyLedgers()

Dim ws As Worksheet, ws1 As Worksheet
Dim LastRow As Long
Set ws = Sheets("INV_LEDGERS")
Set ws1 = Sheets("Ready to upload")

LastRow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

For i = 4 To LastRow
If ws.Range("A" & i) > "" And ws1.Range("A" & i + 1) = "" Then
    ws.Range("A" & i & ":AE" & i).Copy
    ws1.Range("A" & i + 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
Else
    End If
Next

End Sub
```

It doesnt show the error msg anymore, but now it copies the data from `INV_LEDGERS`from the row, where data on sheet `Ready to upload` ends. I mean, that if data on `Ready to upload` has the end on row 82, the code will take the data from `INV_LEDGERS` from 82. row, so basically there are missing 81 rows.

Could you advise me, please?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: You should qualify the Rows reference when you are getting the last row... `LastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row`

Comment: You also need a lastrow for the ws1, and use that as row to start pasting in.

Comment: @ braX Thanks, I've did so, but I'm still receiving the error, there will be probably another mistake.

Comment: What line does the error happen on?

Comment: Did you mean `ws.Range("A" & i & ":AE" & i).Copy` ?

Comment: @braX oh, yes! I did. Thank you for your advice!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given the comments from braX, here is my code.
Since you are always starting on the 4th row of the ledger data, you can just copy the entire section and then paste it to your last row + 1 on your upload sheet.

```
Sub CopyLedgers()

    Dim ws As Worksheet, ws1 As Worksheet
    Dim LastRow, LRow As Long
    Set ws = Sheets("INV_LEDGERS")
    Set ws1 = Sheets("Ready to upload")

    LastRow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    LRow = ws1.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    ws.Range("A4:AE" & LastRow).Copy
    ws1.Range("A" & LRow + 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

    End Sub
```

Comment: actually I receive the 1004 error on the `ws1.Range("A" & LRow + 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues` line

Comment: I can't reproduce your error 1004.  Which 1004 error are you getting?

Comment: Hmm, I've tried it another time and it works fine, already. Maybe I just accidentally changed something..., but many thanks! It works absolutely correct.

Answer (score 0):

Couple things... have used a With statement, and instead of copy/paste, I'm just making ws1.Value=ws.Value:

```
Sub CopyLedgers()
    Dim ws As Worksheet, ws1 As Worksheet, LastRow As Long
    Set ws = Sheets("INV_LEDGERS")
    Set ws1 = Sheets("Ready to upload")
    With ws
        LastRow = .Cells( .Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        For i = 4 To LastRow
            If .Range("A" & i) > "" And ws1.Range("A" & i + 1) = "" Then
                ws1.Range("A" & i + 1 & ":AE" & i + 1).Value = .Range("A" & i & ":AE" & i).Value
            End If
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```

---

**Edit**

```
Sub CopyLedgers()
    Dim ws As Worksheet, ws1 As Worksheet, LastRow As Long
    Set ws = Sheets("INV_LEDGERS")
    Set ws1 = Sheets("Ready to upload")
    With ws
        LastRow = .Cells( .Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        For i = 4 To LastRow
            If IsEmpty(ws1.Range("A" & i + 1)) Then
                ws1.Range("A" & i + 1 & ":AE" & i + 1).Value = .Range("A" & i & ":AE" & i).Value
            End If
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: thank you, it works fine, but the same issue as I filled above. It takes those rows right where data on sheet Ready to upload ends. I mean, that if data on Ready to upload has the end on row 82, the code will take the data from INV_LEDGERS from 82. row, so basically there are missing 81 rows.

Comment: @Srpic I believe your If statement is the problem; my understanding is that you're not getting the rows between 4 and 81 to fill-in, but you are getting row 82 (last row) to fill-in.  You have this additional check about ws.A&i which shouldn't be necessary if you're filling in the blanks for ws1.  If IsEmpty(ws1.Range("A" & i +1)) Then

Comment: Yes, you are right, the check about ws.A&i is quite useless and I've removed it, already. And yes, you understood it correctly. It copies those data (from "INV_LEDGERS") only from the last row in "Ready to upload" sheet, not from the first one as it should.

Comment: @Srpic Please let me know if my Edit post fixes that issue.

Comment: Unfortunately not, still the same. I'm still getting uncomplete data, the same as previously.

Comment: @Srpic ws1 may contain different data than in ws, but if ws1 is missing data, it will copy from ws, correct?  Just making sure, as the answer selected doesn't have the If check, just copy pastes the entirety of ws to ws1.

Comment: @Srpic Odd that it's not working for you... I was just testing it and it worked for me, willing in all rows if A# was blank (on ws1).

Comment: correct. ws will contain everytime different data than ws1, but there is probably necessary to find the end on ws1 and then paste data from ws.

Comment: @Srpic I can see one issue with that process; if the last row of ws1 is empty and needs to be filled in, then you would miss it, considering row count of rows 4:ws.lastrow may be different from 5:ws1.lastrow

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156373/discussion-between-cyril-and-srpic).